# ADF Pipeline to Succeed even if activity fails

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline, azure-synapse

I have a pipeline which i'm working on, i'm doing a lookup to check if few files are there, if the folder path is not there i have to perform certain processes, when the folder path is not present, the lookup activity fails and the red-line flow triggers and does few post-processes.

When those post-processes succeed, the overall pipeline fails, the error message says the lookup failed so overall pipeline also failed, I want my overall pipeline to also show succeed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-failure-error-handling
This documentation says it'll succeed but it still fails.

[image]

Comment: please share the screenshot/image of your overall pipeline/flow as that would help up analyze the cause

Comment: Hey @Nandan, it's for professional purposes, I cannot share it!
The flow goes like this, I have a ADLS path, from which i have to read few files, if the files are present the lookup activity succeeds, then I use the green-line flow to perform certain activities, if the folder path are not present, the lookup activity fails stating the path doesnot exist, I then use the red-line flow to perform certain activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make your pipeline successful, you need to implement `DO-IF-SKIP-ELSE`. That is you can add a dummy `Wait activity` on skipping of true block activity.

Check the **pipeline image:**
[image]

- Adding dummy activity when true activities are skipped will make your pipeline success.

Comment: Thanks Man!
Just one small confirmation, If Set Variable 1 fails and then False Activity also Fails, then on skip Dummy Wait succeeds, this will definitely lead to overall pipeline failure right?

Comment: Yes.  **`Pipeline is a success if and only if all leaves succeed.`**

Answer (score 2):

PFB my doc :

https://datasharkx.files.wordpress.com/2021/08/datasharkx-data-factory-pipeline-conditional-paths-and-outcomes.pdf

from my blog :

https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/

[image]

Yours is a case of  DO-IF-ELSE block :
• when Act_1 activity succeeds: one node activity, Upon Success,
succeeded, and the other node activity, Upon Failure, is skipped and
its parent node succeeds; so overall pipeline succeeds
• when Act_1 activity fails: one node activity, Upon Success, is skipped
and its parent node failed; so overall pipeline failed

Comment: Any suggestions how I can handle this? I have to handle the path not found error.
And this handling should result in overall pipeline success too

Comment: Thanks Nandan for the documentation and explanation, really helped me understand ADF more!